# Taking a screenshot of certain section of screen in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a section of my screen and then store that information in an image array. Is there a way to modify this class:
http://pastebin.com/PDPPxmPT
so that it will allow me to take a screenshot of a specific area? For example, if I wanted the x, y pixel origins of the bitmap to be 200, 200 and the x, y destinations to be 600, 700, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please just post your code in your question, and not on Pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mod it [here](http://pastebin.com/JmCJ4Qer)

EDIT : Here's the code

```
public static Color[,] takeScreenshot(int x=0, int y=0, int width=0, int height = 0)
        {
    if (width==0)
        width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    if (height==0)
        height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            Bitmap screenShotBMP = new Bitmap(width,
                height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            Graphics screenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShotBMP);

            screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(x,
                y, 0, 0, new Size(width,height),
                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            screenShotGraphics.Dispose();

            return bitmap2imagearray(screenShotBMP);
        } 

public static Color[,] bitmap2imagearray(Bitmap b)
        {
            Color[,] imgArray = new Color[b.Width, b.Height];
            for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
                {
                    imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y);
                }
            }
            return imgArray;
        }
```

Comment: Please just post your code in your answer, and not on Pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but including the code from pastebin as it'll likely disappear sometime in the future and may be useful for others.

```
    public static Color[,] takeScreenshot()
    {
        Bitmap screenShotBMP = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics screenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShotBMP);

        screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
            System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
            CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        screenShotGraphics.Dispose();

        return bitmap2imagearray(screenShotBMP);
    } 

    public static Color[,] bitmap2imagearray(Bitmap b)
    {
        Color[,] imgArray = new Color[b.Width, b.Height];
        for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
            {
                imgArray[x, y] = b.GetPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
        return imgArray;
    }
```